# Anyone know how to activate Salesforce Walkthroughs

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce1-platform

I've discovered in one of my Developer orgs a new Salesforce functionality already present since [Summer '15 Release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_walkthroughs.htm) (?).

[image: Create - Salesforce Walktrough]

[image: Salesforce Walktrough]

[image: Salesforce Walktrough Tool]

But I don't have it in other developer orgs or sandboxes for customers.
Anyone knows how to activate it? Because I don't find a lot about it on Google or Salesforce sites. Only this in [help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000214147&language=en_US)

Comment: I know this may not help - but I plan to use whatfix for something similar - http://whatfix.com/business/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=whatfix&utm_content=Whatfix_Brand&utm_campaign=Brand&gclid=CJv5lvHo8MsCFRG3GwodkskO3g  If you do find out how to enable it I'd love to know.

Answer (score 2):

I checked in the release readiness group and it is no longer being persued by Salesforce. They suggested looking into walkme in this thread [here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oku&fId=0D53000002fAod7&s1oid=00D300000000iTz&OpenCommentForEdit=1&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1nid=0DB30000000072L&emtm=1459708194781&s1). Looked awesome though, too bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think that was part of Admin Analytics Pilot or another Pilot with Spring '15
Here's a link to that video: http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/Tf-tKYPrC3xqIGSNGTLH9w

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce initially brought in the walkthroughs to change its content strategy. The idea of the feature was to guide and educate user with real-time contextual help within the platform, without the need for them to refer to any external resources.

But now it looks like Salesforce is not doing much with it. Probably we can expect some news about in the upcoming Dreamforce.

If you are curious, you could check out this article that explains why Salesforce, Oracle and ServiceNow adopted these walkthroughs - [Why Multi Billion-dollar Enterprises Are Adopting Interactive Walkthroughs](http://academy.whatfix.com/enterprises-adopted-interactive-walkthroughs/)

P.S - You could use 3rd party interactive guidance and engagement platforms like [Whatfix](https://whatfix.com?utm_source=sf_stackexchange&utm_medium=referral_se_17&utm_campaign=se_answer_gokul&utm_content=se_answers_link&utm_term=SE_17). It works like a breeze on Salesforce.

[image: Whatfix on Salesforce]